# Angular 4 error - ERROR in ./src/main.ts Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory'

Tags: angular, build, production-environment

During the angular build for production (`ng build --prod`) I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/bandpay/stg-bandpay-client/src'
 @ ./src/main.ts 3:0-74
 @ multi ./src/main.ts

....
```

what does that mean, how to resolve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by:
ng build --env=prod

Comment: Is this the same as doing ng build --prod? I was getting the same error and this has fixed it

Comment: For me, only this fixed the issue at the time.

Comment: This is not a great solution as it disable the ahead of time compiler https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Answer (score -1):

Using ng build --env=prod will not reduce the build size.
The file size will remain same as  dev build.